# I am to make a small game, and I want it to add up the total sum at the end of the turn

Tags: java

So this is my code now:

```
public class PigTry2
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Variables

        int start;
        int total;


        //Methods

        Scanner quest = new Scanner (System.in);
        die1 x = new die1 ();
        die2 z = new die2 ();


        // Game

        System.out.println("Hello. Would you like to play PIG? 1 for yes");
        start = quest.nextInt();
        if (start == 1){
            x.roll();
            z.roll();

            System.out.println("You roll: "+ z.getEyes() + " " + x.getEyes());
            do {
                System.out.println("Would you like to roll again");
                start = quest.nextInt();
                if (start == 1)
                x.roll();
                z.roll();
                System.out.println("You roll: "+ z.getEyes() + " " + x.getEyes());
            } while(z.getEyes() != 1 && x.getEyes() != 1);

            total = 

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a few different methods, and I want to add up the total sum of the rolls that happen.  I simply can't figure out how to do this. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: you can say what language you are making this game in. it looks that .NET but it could be flash

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. this way people that have a Java background would be better the take a look at this

Comment: do you want to count each `.roll()` call?, sorry but is not clear enough

Comment: Yes. I need the total at the end to be counted up, if the user deicdes to not roll again.

The premise is that if you roll a 1, you lose your total amount of rolls, and the turn is passed on, so I need a total count at the end of the users turn.

Comment: what about a counter variable that is incremented inside or after a call to `roll()` something like this: `x.roll(); counter++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, I'd suggest this:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Variables

    int start;
    int total = 0;


    //Methods

    Scanner quest = new Scanner (System.in);
    die1 x = new die1 ();
    die2 z = new die2 ();


    // Game

    System.out.println("Hello. Would you like to play PIG? 1 for yes");
    start = quest.nextInt();
    if (start == 1){
        x.roll();
        z.roll();
        total += 2; //You just rolled twice, so lets increment by 2

        System.out.println("You roll: "+ z.getEyes() + " " + x.getEyes());
        do {
            System.out.println("Would you like to roll again");
            start = quest.nextInt();
            if (start == 1)
            x.roll();
            z.roll();
            total += 2; //EDIT: Rolled again, so ingrement by 2 again
            System.out.println("You roll: "+ z.getEyes() + " " + x.getEyes());
        } while(z.getEyes() != 1 && x.getEyes() != 1);

        System.out.println("Total amount of rolls: " + total);

    }
}
```

Something else: Users won't be able to cancel rolling until they throw a "1", because the if-statement in the do-while-loop won't quit the loop. You could use a flag to indicate, whether the user want's to keep rolling:

```
boolean finished = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to roll again");
    start = quest.nextInt();
    if (start == 1) {
        x.roll();
        z.roll();
        total += 2; //EDIT: Rolled again, so ingrement by 2 again
        System.out.println("You roll: "+ z.getEyes() + " " + x.getEyes());
    } else {
        finished = true;
    }
} while(z.getEyes() != 1 && x.getEyes() != 1 && !finished);
```